# An international affair: Find the common property in incorrect equations

Tags: mathematics, pattern, lateral-thinking

Chaos at the international conference for world leaders: What should have been a peaceful exchange of ideas for common growth quickly exploded into hostility shortly after the German speaker addressed the USA delegates with accusations:

> "We have recently discovered hacking attempts at our security network.
> Someone deliberately gave us faulty processors, such that we now
> compute
>
> **1 + 1 = 8**
>
> We think, the NSA is trying to spy on us!"

The Americans jumped up and shouted:

> "Outrageous! Why is everybody always suspecting us for such things?
> Just so you know, we are victims, not aggressors. Checking our
> security protocols we've found a vulnerability. Our processors gave
>
> **2 + 2 = 6**
>
> And guess who wrote our software? The Italians!"

The Italian minister's face went through a spectacular range of colours, finishing with purple as he shouts out:

> "You accuse us of putting deliberate vulnerabilities in software we
> distribute? Or do you just think we can't program? Either way, we will
> take up American traditions and sue you out of your wits! And we have
> proof that your harmful allegations are wrong. Checking our own
> computer systems with the prime OS installed - which, I may add, has
> been provided by an American company not known for their security, we
> could already see the same miscalculations you've just thrown in our
> face! But we tested further and realized that also
>
> **16 + 16 = 12**
>
> However, the security expert advising us on our network was a Czech
> immigrant, so if you want to point any fingers..."

"I don't believe it!" the Czech ambassador to Italy barks out.

> "First you only pay dumping prices for our experts and beg me to bring
> them into your country, and then you call them spies? I can only
> assume all of this is a political ploy initiated by our Finnish
> friends, who not only live close to Russia, but also provided most of
> the mobile telecommunication in our countries. We have recently seen
> some of those devices miscalculate
>
> **32 + 32 = 18**
>
> and
>
> **64 + 64 = 24**
>
> So..."

But before the Finnish delegation has time to react, the meeting is interrupted by the session chair.

> "Gentlemen, Gentlemen! Please calm down. I have just received
> intelligence that an international crime organisation has secretly
> spread a virus who, as I've been led to believe, is responsible for all
> the effects you have just described.

**Can you tell what this mystic virus is actually doing?**
(i.e. we seek a method/algorithm/equation/instruction which makes all those equations come true.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What the virus does, is that

> it translates each number to the speaker's native language, then counts its letters

and uses that number to compute the outcome.

So:

> Germany: 1 + 1 -> eins + eins -> 4 + 4 = 8
>  America: 2 + 2 -> two + two -> 3 + 3 = 6
>  Italy: 16 + 16 -> sedici + sedici -> 6 + 6 = 12
>  Czech: 32 + 32 -> třicet dva + třicet dva  -> 9 + 9 = 18
>  Czech: 64 + 64 -> šedesát čtyři + šedesát čtyři  -> 12 + 12 = 24

Comment: If you are correct, that is pure genius!

Comment: @dmg: I wanted to post both puzzles close to each other, but you were too fast on the other one. It was solved before I had this one posted!

Comment: @sqb: did you solve it independently from my other number puzzle, or was it spoilt by it? Anyway, great work.

Comment: @BmyGuest what other puzzle? :)